# WCF security issue in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + Silverlight 3.0. I host a WCF service in IIS 7.0. My question is, besides using https + basicHttpBinding, are there any other security solutions? I want to find a security solution which does not need certificate on server side. I am not sure whether message security works without certificate and works also for Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to be using a certificate of some sort on the server side (I'm assuming you weren't referring only to SSL, but also to putting a certificate on the box to support WS-Security standards), the best you're going to be able to do is Username/Password.

Here's a link on [Implementing Username Password & WS-Security with Silverlight](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815091929/http://geekswithblogs.net/SunnyCoder/archive/2009/03/15/username-password-amp-ws-security-with-silverlight.aspx).

Comment: Looks like in order to implement message level security, we need to manually craft the SOAP header and body?

Comment: Another question is whether using the solution mentioned in your recommended document needs to setup certificate at server side? Thanks!

Comment: Because Silverlight doesn't have the objects available in the Web Service Extensions pack (which Microsoft used to implement the WS-Security standards), you do you have to craft the SOAP header manually. This method also does not require any certificates be installed at all.

Comment: Thanks! I want to confirm that using the method in the document, only password is encrypted? Other parts of SOAP message is still un-encrypted?

Comment: If memory serves, this won't get you any encryption in the message. It will only provide an authentication mechanism. If you want any kind of WS-Security standard encyrption, you're going to need an X.509 Certificate. You'll need to install it on the server and provide each client acess to the public key.

Comment: Thanks! I want to confirm with you that even if it is called message level seucrity, the message itself is not encrypted (e.g. the password field), and it relys on underlying security communication protocols, like https to provide encryption?

Comment: If you want transport level security (all traffic over the wire is encrypted) you have to use SSL. If you're looking for message based encryption (doesn't rely on any protocols), you need an X.509 certificate which will get used for the encryption and signing of the message. The later can be done over plain http.